# Rock-Paper-Scissors Game

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm currently pretty stuck on this rock, paper, scissors program and would greatly appreciate some help. I have looked through other posts concerning rock, paper, scissors programs but I'm still stuck.

The error I'm getting currently is When I ask the user to choose 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scissors' it will keep asking it a couple more times and then I get an error. Also, it seems to me that a good portion of the posts I look at involve concepts that I haven't used in class, so I'm not comfortable with them.

```
      choices = [ 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors' ]
# 1. Greetings & Rules
def showRules():
    print("\n*** Rock-Paper-Scissors ***\n")

    print("\nEach player chooses either Rock, Paper, or Scissors."
          "\nThe winner is determined by the following rules:"
          "\n   Scissors cuts Paper   ->  Scissors wins"
          "\n   Paper covers Rock     ->  Paper wins"
          "\n   Rock smashes Scissors ->  Rock wins\n")

# 2. Determine User Choice
def getUserChoice():
    usrchoice = input("\nChoose from Rock, Paper or Scissors: ").lower()
    if (usrchoice not in choices):
        usrchoice = input("\nChoose again from Rock, Paper or Scissors: ").lower()
    print('User chose:', usrchoice)
    return usrchoice

# 3. Determine Computer choice
def getComputerChoice():
    from random import randint
    randnum = randint(1, 3)
    cptrchoice = choices(randnum)
    print('Computer chose:', cptrchoice)
    return randnum

# 4. Determine Winner
def declareWinner(user, computer):
    if usrchoice == cptrchoice:
        print('TIE!!')
    elif (usrchoice == 'Scissors' and cptrchoice == 'Rock'
         or usrchoice == 'Rock' and cptrchoice == 'Paper'
         or usrchoice == 'Paper' and cptrchoice == 'Scissors'):
        print('You lose!! :(')
    else:
        print('You Win!! :)')


#5. Run program
def playGame():
    showRules()                     # Display the title and game rules
    user = getUserChoice()       # Get user selection (Rock, Paper, or Scissors)
    computer = getComputerChoice()  # Make and display computer's selection
    declareWinner(user, computer)   # decide and display winner
```

Comment: Given that `choices` *doesn't* contain lowercase strings, how do you expect `input("...").lower()` to ever work? Also, please read up on https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Check your list. Are those lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few problems with the code:

First is you are converting `user input` to lowercase but your list items are not. So the check will fail.

```
choices = [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors' ]
```

Second thing is you are calling choice(randnum) which will throw an error as you have to use `[]` to retrieve element from list.

```
cptrchoice = choices[randnum]
```

Third is what happens if you enter invalid string. You only check with `if` but you need `while loop`

```
while (usrchoice not in choices):
    usrchoice = getUserChoice() #input("\nChoose again from Rock, Paper or Scissors: ").lower()
```

Fourth is in `declareWinner`, your `params` are `user` and `computer` but then you are using `usrchoice` and `cptrchoice` in `if` conditions

```
def declareWinner(usrchoice, cptrchoice):
    if usrchoice == cptrchoice:
```

Try this and give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

here is what i did.

you play until you win. it uses the number scheme from chmod to determine wins and losses, and ties. it does not report losses or ties. i can't remember exactly how i figure this out. i was in the zone.

```
import random
print("Play until you win!") 
print("Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
class GameEngine:
    def __init__(self, computer):
        self.computer = computer
starter = GameEngine(random.choice([-4,-2,-1]))
class Player:
    def __init__ (self, options):
        self.options = options
play = Player({"rock":4,"paper":2,"scissors":1})
class ScoreBoard:
    def __init__(self, score, loss):
        self.score = score
        self.loss = loss
while True:
    match = ScoreBoard(play.options[input("Choose: ")]+starter.computer,[0,-1,-2,3]) #the dictionary key pair corresponding to the input of rock paper or scissors
    if match.score in match.loss:
        starter.computer = 0
    else:
        print("You win!")
        break
```

Comment: An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal.  Remember, you are leaving solutions not just for the original asker but for future users.  Code-only answers may be downvoted.