# rock paper scissor python program input error

Tags: python

```py
import random


def rpc():
    a = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"]

    b = random.choice(a)
    
    print(b)

    userinput = input('please type rock, paper or scissor:')
    if userinput == "":
        print("please print the right thing")
        rpc()
        
    if userinput != "rock":
        print("type the right thing!")
        rpc()
        
    if userinput != "paper":
        print("type the right thing!")
        rpc()
        
    if userinput != "scissor":
        print("type the right thing!")
        rpc()
    
    
    while b == userinput:
        print("it is a draw, do you want to play another one?")
        c = input("type 'y' if you want to play one more time or press 'n': ")
        if c == 'y':
            rpc()
        elif c =='n':
            break
        else:
            print("print the right words please")

    if b == 'rock' and userinput == 'paper':
        print("you win!")
        rpc()

    elif b == 'rock' and userinput == 'scissor':
        print("you lost")
        rpc()

    elif b == 'paper' and userinput == 'scissor':
        print("you win!")
        rpc()

    elif b == 'paper' and userinput == 'rock':
        print("you lost!")
        rpc()

    elif b == 'scissor' and userinput == 'rock':
        print("you win!")
        rpc()

    elif b == 'scissor' and userinput == 'paper':
        print("you lost!")
        rpc()

rpc()
```

This is my code for rock paper and scissor, it's pretty simple but when I run my code and input my rock, paper and scissor, I get my please print the right thing statement, O have no idea why it's happening, any help would be wonderful, thank you!

Comment: Not directly related: name your variables appropriately. It might cost you a few more milliseconds of typing, but it will save you hours of thinking about your code.

Comment: And split your code in logical pieces. Here you could have a `game()` function, a `ask_move()` function, a `compute_winer()` function a `show_result()` function. Made up examples but you see the point: each function should focus on a single thing that is easy to reason about.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190894/rock-paper-scissors-game

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rock-Paper-Scissors Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190894/rock-paper-scissors-game)

Comment: Have a look into this [ask]

Comment: You can't get past three different `!=` conditions with a single value.

Comment: and when you'll have everything else fixed, you'll encounter a max depth recursion error: an opportunity to discover what this website's name means

Answer (score 1):

Lets clean this up....

```
userinput = input('please type rock, paper or scissor:')
while userinput not in acceptable_inputs:
    userinput = input('please type rock, paper or scissor:')
opponents_choice = random.choice(objects)
# Check and print. Loop to keep playing - 2 out of 3 wins....
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
def winner(riya,siya):
    if (riya==siya):
        return None
    elif (riya=="s"):
        if (siya=="p"):
            return False
        elif(siya=="k"):
            return True
    elif (riya=="p"):
        if (siya=="s"):
            return False
        elif (siya=="k"):
            return True
    elif (riya=="k"):
        if (siya=="s"):
            return True
        elif (siya=="p"):
            return False
        
print("riya pick: stone(s) paper(p) sessior(k)") 
a= random.randint(1,3) 
if a==1:
    riya="s"
elif a==2:
    riya="p" 
elif a==3:
    riya="k"
siya=input(" siya pick: stone(s) paper(p) sessior(k)")
b=winner(riya,siya)
print(f"riya pick{riya}")
print(f"siya pick {siya}")
if b==None:
    print("tie")
elif b:
    print("winner")`enter code here`
else:enter code here
    print("loose")
```